# Changes to $PATH won't save after closing the terminal session

Tags: command-line, bash

I downloaded the latest version of Scala and saved it to /opt folder. Then I tried to add /opt/scala-2.11.2/bin to the PATH in order to have easier access to commands like scala and scalac. After executing the command :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/scala-2.11.2/bin/
```

and then :

```
echo $PATH
```

I see the path in there. At that time I can also use the commands scala and scalac.

Then if I close the terminal and restart  , the path /opt/scala-2.11.2/bin/ is not in echo $PATH anymore. And thus I can not execute the commands . What is my problem ?

Comment: Add it to your .profile file, [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path) an example

Comment: This is what I have done. Still does not work.

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH:$/opt/scala-2.11.2/bin"
fi

Comment: You have to do it outside of the `if .. then`, because `$HOME/bin` does not exists, put it in the last line of the .profile file

Answer (score 0):

put that command at the end of the file  `.bashrc` inside your home directory than do a

> source .bashrc